# How to read a huge csv faster?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, io, pyarrow

I tried using pyarrow without success. My code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", engine='pyarrow')
```

I get this error:

```
"pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: straddling object straddles two block boundaries (try to increase block size?)"
```

I cannot find any argument to change the block size. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can checkout dask library: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html

Comment: Thank you! this method is actually fast to read, but incredibly slow to work with. Even df.head() takes forever. I tried to convert to pandas df but it just never finished. When I first created the df (before saving as csv) working with pandas was super fast in comparison.

Comment: I see, well good luck with your work :)

Comment: It sounds like you had some success, with just Pandas, but found some part of the process too slow. Can you edit your question to include the code that worked, including a sample of the operations you used with Pandas, and then articulate which part was too slow, and by how much? Do you need all the columns, can you pare down the CSV in a preprocessing step?

Comment: I think the issue is that I have very large strings as fields. In reality they are lists, but because I cannot save them as such I converted them to comma-separated strings when saving as csv. And no, when loading the csv file I don't load all columns, just the necessary. I didn't find any solution yet other than recreating the data frame from scratch, rather than loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a `block_size` you will need to use PyArrow directly:

```
from pyarrow import csv

# read CSV using PyArrow with ReadOptions
read_options = csv.ReadOptions(
    block_size=1024,  # <= define a block size here
)

table = csv.read_csv("file.csv", read_options=read_options)

# convert PyArrow Table to pandas DataFrame
df = table.to_pandas()
```

---

You can also use more efficient file formats to store and load large datasets, such as:

- [Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/): Parquet stores data column-wise rather than row-wise like CSV (useful when loading part of the columns). It offers compression and efficient encoding. Pandas has methods for [creating](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html) and [reading](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_parquet.html) Parquet files as dataframes.
- [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html): Pickle implements binary protocols for serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure. The files are serialized representations of Python objects and can be much smaller in size compared to text-based formats like CSV. Pandas has methods for [creating](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) and [reading](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html) Pickle files as dataframes.

Comment: Unfortunately I keep getting the same error. My file is 1.22 Gb if that is relevant.

Comment: You can try using a more efficient file format, like Parquet or Pickle, rather than CSV.

Comment: Amazing! this worked. Feel free to write it as an answer :)

Comment: @Caterina Great to hear! I've edited the answer to include information about using different file formats.

Answer (score 0):

#### About the `ArrowInvalid` exception

In the case of csv-files, *straddling object straddles two block boundaries* means that at least one line fell into 3 reading blocks, whereas for correct reading it is required that each line should be within a maximum of two. Here's an example of how to recreate this error with the following data:

```
data = 'value\nAB\nABC123456DEF\nAB'   # csv data

print('Blocks of 6 bytes:\n' 
      '------------------')
for p in range(0, len(data), 6):
    print(repr(data[p:p+6]))
```

As you can see in the last 3 lines below, the third entry `"ABC123456DEF\n"` of the data extends over 3 blocks of 6 bytes:

```
Blocks of 6 bytes:
------------------
'value\n'
'AB\nABC'
'123456'
'DEF\nAB'
```

So, if you read these data as a csv file with `block_size=6`, you'll encounter the `ArrowInvalid` exception:

```
from pyarrow import csv
from io import BytesIO

data = 'value\nAB\nABC123456DEF\nAB'
read_options = csv.ReadOptions(block_size=6)
csv.read_csv(BytesIO(data.encode()), read_options=read_options)   # ArrowInvalid expected
```

To avoid this exception, we can define a block size large enough to cover the longest record. In the above case, the longest record is of size 12, so we can read the data using `block_size=12` (it can be less, but with no guarantee of success in general case).

Pandas<=2.2 sticks to the default `block_size`, which, as we can see in the [Arrow Apache documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/api/formats.html#_CPPv4N5arrow3csv11ReadOptions10block_sizeE), is 1 megabyte. Since this is not enough in your case, you will have to try a `block_size` bigger than 1048576 bytes with `pyarrow` itself, as in the example above.

#### Reading big CSV files with `pyarrow`

Let's create some data similar to [your example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78049001/14909621):

```
def gen_data(min_number=0, max_number=1_000, min_count=1<<10, max_count=1<<20, seed=0):
    from numpy.random import default_rng
    rng = default_rng(seed)
    while True:
        size = rng.integers(min_count, max_count)
        yield ','.join(map(str, rng.integers(min_number, max_number, size)))

from itertools import count

data_file = 'test.csv'
rec_id = count()
seq = gen_data()
headers = ['id', 'col1', 'col2']
file_size = int(1.22 * (1<<30))    # create a csv file of size >= 1.22 Gb
sep = ' '

with open(data_file, 'w') as file:
    size = file.write(sep.join(headers) + '\n')
    while size < file_size:
        size += file.write(str(next(rec_id)) + sep)
        size += file.write(next(seq) + sep)
        size += file.write(next(seq) + '\n')
```

Hardly you would like to keep all the data in memory, most probably you want just get some answer about data. This can be done in parts with [pyarrow.csv.open_csv](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.open_csv.html). For example, if the initial request is *"Collect common items along columns"*, we can do it like this:

```
from pyarrow.csv import open_csv

# find the number of megabytes to cover the longest line of a data file
megabyte = 1<<20
max_len = max(len(line) for line in open(data_file, 'rb'))
block_size = megabyte * (1 + (max_len-1) // megabyte)       

read_options = csv.ReadOptions(block_size=block_size)
parse_options = csv.ParseOptions(delimiter=' ')
convert_options = csv.ConvertOptions(include_columns=['col1', 'col2'])

def reduce_intersect(table_column, sep=','):
    from functools import reduce
    return reduce(set.intersection, 
                  table_column.to_pandas().str.split(sep).map(set))

with open_csv(data_file, read_options, parse_options, convert_options) as file:
    common = {}    # collect here common items along columns
    batch = file.read_next_batch()
    for col in batch.schema.names:
        common[col] = reduce_intersect(batch[col])
    if any(common.values()):
        for batch in file:
            for col in (col for col, data in common.items() if data):
                common[col].intersection_update(reduce_intersect(batch[col]))
            if not any(common.values()):
                break
```